# How to get distinct values from csv file column into a combo box?

Tags: winforms, csv, foreach, combobox, distinct

In my WinForms app I wrote a code to get a distinct values from a specific column(skipping the first row) and display them in `combobox`. But I'm getting all existing (repeated)entries from that column.

```
  var collection_of_objects =
       (from line in File.ReadAllLines("file.csv").Skip(1)
        let parts = line.Split(',')
        select new
         {
            EventID=parts[0],
            EventName = parts[1],    
         }
        ).Distinct().ToList();

        foreach (var obj in collection_of_objects)
        {
            cmbSelectEvent.Items.Add(obj.EventName);
        }
```

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Can `EventName` have doubles with another `EventID`? In that case your `Distinct()` will not help off course

Comment: @GuidoG Yes,EventID +EventName is unique.I also removed ` line EventID=parts[0]` from above code but still I'm getting list of repeated values from the csv file column.

Comment: So the same `EventName` can appear with another `EventID` ? Than `Distinct()` is not able to filter out double `EventNames`

Comment: I  removed line `EventID=parts[0]` from above code but still I'm getting list of repeated values from the csv file column.

Comment: can you add sample data

Comment: @MunnaExtreme So in my csv file I have currently 12 rows and the combobox displays list of (I changed names):dog,dog,dog,dog,cat,cat,cat,cat,cat,mouse,mouse,cow.

Comment: I also replaced Distinct() to combobox property: ` cmbSelectEvent.Items.Add(obj.EventName.Distinct())` but it's not working either.

Answer (score 0):

My corrected code that worked out finally:

```
         var collection_of_objects =
        (from line in File.ReadAllLines("csvFile.csv").Skip(1)
        let parts = line.Split(',')
        select new
         {
            EventName = parts[1],    
         }
        ).Distinct().ToList();

        foreach (var obj in collection_of_objects)
        {
            cmbSelectEvent.Items.Add(obj.EventName);
        }
```

thank You for your comments!